# Adobe Brackets - get path of current extension

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm looking for the canonical way to access the directory that belongs to a running extension. At the moment I have this kludge. It allows me to access a .json located in the same directory as main.js.

```
var support_dir = brackets.app.getApplicationSupportDirectory(),
    precursor_path,
    precursor_file = "package.json";   // where this represents some config file.

support_dir += "/extensions/user/zeffii.precursor/";
precursor_path = support_dir + precursor_file;

var prototypes;
$.getJSON(precursor_path, function (data) {
    prototypes = data;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var ExtensionUtils = brackets.getModule("utils/ExtensionUtils");

var path = ExtensionUtils.getModulePath(module);
```

(Where `module` comes from the `define(function (require, exports, module) {` at the top of your extension module).